# Java Script Return Value

Tags: javascript

I new to Javascript i want to know how to return true,false value from javascript function to code behind so that my further code should not execute

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function CheckAge(age)
    {
        if (age > 18)

            return true
        else
            return false;
    }


</script>
```

Here is .cs code

```
protected void btnAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool check=false;
        try
        {

            btnAge.Attributes.Add("onClick", string.Format("return CheckAge({0});", check ? "false" : "true"));
            if (check)
                Response.Write("You Are Eligible");
            else
                Response.Write("You Are Not Eligible");
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {                
          Response.Write(err.Message);
        }
    }
```

Where i am going wrong

Comment: Well, for one you're calling a server-side function as if it was a client-side one, and you're passing it a boolean instead of the number it expects.

Comment: You can't do that! JavaScript = Client, C# = Server - you'll need to use AJAX or post the data to the server and use a postback

Comment: Simpler: `function CheckAge(age) {return age > 18;}`

Comment: You're not actually invoking the function when you click the button.  You're just adding a click handler to it which would invoke the function the next time you click it.  (Except since you're using post-backs the next time you click it you'll just do the same thing again.)  If your logic is in JavaScript then there's no need for server-side code or post-backs at all here.  Just use a normal HTML button and set its click event to execute the JavaScript function.

Comment: Also, note in your server-side code that you explicitly set `check` to `false` and then a couple of lines later you have some conditionals looking at its value, which will *always* result in `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You are fundamentally confused.

On the server, you have a program, written in C#, which is supposed to generate a web-page.

The web-page is effectively a second program, written in Javascript and HTML, that runs on the browser much later; it creates the UI you have in mind.

There is no live interaction between the server-side C# and the client-side Javascript.

Once you have understood this paradigm, you will be able to build a functioning web-page.

---

On a minor note, this code makes me crazy:

```
function CheckAge(age)
    {
        if (age > 18)

            return true
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Grrr.  `age > 18` is itself an expression with the value true or false.  You should just write:

```
function CheckAge(age)
    {
        return (age > 18)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The difficulty i am facing is that i want my function which is in .cs file should work on basis of TRUE OR FALSE now only false condition is being executed,how will i do that ? Hope i made my self clear.

Comment: The .cs file runs before -- sometimes *long* before -- the Javascript runs, and on a different computer.  It cannot use data from the Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CheckAge(age) {
        if (age > 18) {
            return "true";
        } else {
            return "false";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Braces aren't necessary on single line statements